# How to calculate covariance matrix properly using Bartlett's formula

Tags: covariance-matrix, asymptotic-covariance

Batlett's formula for asympthotic covariance matrix $C$ is given as:

$$c_{ij}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\rho_{k-i}+\rho_{k+i}-2\rho_{k}\rho_i)(\rho_{k-j}+\rho_{k+j}-2\rho_{k}\rho_j)$$

where $\rho$ is the **sample** autocorrelations. [Brockwell and Davis (2016)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-29854-2) mentions this form of the formula as "*more convenient for the computational purposes*". However I am confused because of the infinite sum here. So can someone tell me how to use this formula properly for computation.

Comment: I think what is confusing about this formula is "what is the underlying model" that causes that formula to make sense ? I printed out the bartlett paper but it looks complex. If you have access to JSTOR, the paper is there.  I suggest checking that paper out.

Comment: @mlfton can you share the name of paper?

Comment: Sure. The name of it is "Theoretical specifcation and sampling properties of auto-correlated time series". But, I was just gonna to comment again and say that, based on your comment,  I looked at Brockwell and Davis and 221-237 looks like nice coverage ( much more readable than Bartlett ) so I am de-suggesting the Bartlett paper !!!!!! At the same time, maybe you prefer Bartlett's paper so check it out if you want.  I was never a fan of Brockwell and Davis but lately I'm starting to  realize how good it is.

Comment: It makes no sense to equate *sample* autocorrelations with an asymptotic expression, which is a theoretical, model-based value.  What exactly are you trying to find, then?

Comment: @whuber there are papers i am trying to understand, which uses Covariance Matrix estimated by this formula for the related work (see Baillie and Chung 2001).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days more research and I finally found the answer. With large sample size ($n$) this equation gives a good aproximation to $C_{m\times m}$ (with $m < n$ as an arbitrary value). There is a tiny modification though: the upper limit of the sum should be $n-m$:

$$\hat{c}_{ij}= \sum_{k=1}^{n-m} (\rho_{k-i}+\rho_{k+i}-2\rho_{k}\rho_i)(\rho_{k-j}+\rho_{k+j}-2\rho_{k}\rho_j)\\\lim_{n\to \infty} \hat{c}_{ij} =c_{ij}$$

One can get good results for applications with (for example) $n\geq 1000$. And for $m$, small values (like $m\leq30$ ) are suggested. Below I shared a code for better understandig of the implementation:

```py
def Bartlett_C(scor:np.array, nobs:int, dimc:int=30):

    # scor : sample autocorrelations
    # dimc : dimension of C matrix (m value, above)
    # nobs : number of observations (n value, above)
    # for large data, using @njit with this code is suggested
    
    # -------------------------------------------------
    C = np.zeros((dimc, dimc), dtype=np.float32)
    # row, column counters-----------------------------
    for i in range(dimc):
        for j in range(i, dimc):
            ii, jj = i + 1, j + 1
            cij = 0.0
    # bartlett's formula-------------------------------
            for k in range(1, nobs - dimc):
                _2rk = 2 * scor[k]
                kdi, kdj = abs(k - ii), abs(k - jj)
                a = scor[kdi] + scor[k + ii] - _2rk * scor[ii]
                b = scor[kdj] + scor[k + jj] - _2rk * scor[jj]
                cij += a * b
    # -------------------------------------------------
            C[i, j] = C[j, i] = cij
    # -------------------------------------------------
    return C
```